# Platform game collisions with Block

Tags: java, collision-detection, platformer

I am trying to create a platform game and doing wrong collision detection with the blocks.

Here's my code

```
// Variables
GTimer jump = new GTimer(1000);
boolean onground = true;

// The update method
public void update(long elapsedTime){
    MapView.follow(this);
    // Add the gravity
    if (!onground && !jump.active){
        setVelocityY(4);
    }
    // Jumping
    if (isPressed(VK_SPACE) && onground){
        jump.start();
        setVelocityY(-4);
        onground = false;
    }
    if (jump.action(elapsedTime)){
        // jump expired
        jump.stop();
    }
    // Horizontal movement
    setVelocityX(0);
    if (isPressed(VK_LEFT)){
        setVelocityX(-4);
    }
    if (isPressed(VK_RIGHT)){
        setVelocityX(4);
    }
}

// The collision method
public void collision(GObject other){
    if (other instanceof Block){
        // Determine the horizontal distance between centers
        float h_dist = Math.abs((other.getX() + other.getWidth()/2) - (getX() + getWidth()/2));
        // Now the vertical distance
        float v_dist = Math.abs((other.getY() + other.getHeight()/2) - (getY() + getHeight()/2));
        // If h_dist > v_dist horizontal collision else vertical collision
        if (h_dist > v_dist){
            // Are we moving right?
            if (getX()<other.getX()){
                setX(other.getX()-getWidth());
            }
            // Are we moving left?
            else if (getX()>other.getX()){
                setX(other.getX()+other.getWidth());
            }
        } else {
            // Are we moving up?
            if (jump.active){
                jump.stop();
            }
            // We are moving down
            else {
                setY(other.getY()-getHeight());
                setVelocityY(0);
                onground = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the object jumps well but does not fall when moved out of platform. Here's an image describing the problem.

[image: error]

I know I'm not checking underneath the object but I don't know how. The map is a list of objects and should I have to iterate over all the objects???

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38252/circle-rectangle-collision-in-a-tile-map-game/

Comment: I'm not using tilemaps.

Comment: The engine uses QuadTrees

Comment: The QuadTree implementation is private and the collision method is called automatically. The only thing which is accessible from the map is the list of objects

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6257/discussion-between-markus-von-broady-and-sri-harsha-chilakapati)

Comment: What's wrong with arthur's answer from your [question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/38893/1839), it actually answers this question too, which makes this a duplicate. Take the time to implement arthur's answer and ask new questions when you are stuck with it. Repeating the same question over and over will hardly bring you anywhere. voting to close

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an efficient collision detection system](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/making-an-efficient-collision-detection-system)

Answer (score 2):

Collision detection at platform specific games can be implemented utilizing several techniques.

- Speculative Contacts
- Minkowski Difference, etc

The following resources may help you

- http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/03/25/speculative-contacts-an-continuous-collision-engine-approach-part-1/
- http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/12/14/how-to-make-a-2d-platform-game-part-2-collision-detection/
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/86195-platform-game-collision-detection-not-tile-based/